# Swift ios not sure how to add navigation bar to VC in storyboard when using storyboard id

Tags: ios, swift

I am reseting my root VC in my app using:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("testVc")

let navigationController = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
navigationController.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
```

So since I dont have a segue I have a sotyboard id for that VC. The only problem now is that I dont know how to add a navigation bar in my storyboard to that VC.

The VC shows up as completly white/empty in my storyboard but once I run my app and it gets assigned as root it also get a navigation bar which is right, but I would want to add one using storyboard and not code.

If I simply drag a navigation bar in storyboard and start the app. It will result in the navigation bar being placed under the other navigation bar.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not add a navigation bar in the storyboard. We're going to use the navigation controller's navigation bar.

You add a navigation *item* in the storyboard. Now you can configure, in the storyboard, what should be in the navigation bar when you are in a navigation interface.

Comment: Thanks. I added a navigation item but it doesnt show up. I uploaded a image so you can see

Comment: I updated my post with images. You can see that I added item and button. They show up once I start my app, but the VC still remains completly white in storyboard as you can see in the picture

Comment: Well, I don't really see why that matters. I solved the problem you asked about, it seems to me. But if you want to see it in the storyboard, then select the view controller in the storyboard and, in the Attributes inspector, under Simulated Metrics, change the Top Bar pop-up to Navigation Bar (in some form).